# Can you use a custom subdomain with G Suite if it doesn't have anything hosted there?

Tags: google, domains, subdomain, email

I purchased a domain from Namecheap, say `myname.example`. I'm not hosting anything with this domain or or any of its subdomains. I want to create a G Suite account with the subdomain `subdomain.myname.example`, so that I can have Gmail addresses of the form `...@subdomain.myname.example`.

So far, I added the `TXT` record from G Suite to Namespace with the host being the subdomain `subdomain.myname.example`. But G Suite is unable to verify my ownership with this. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can use a custom subdomain setup for your G Suite.  All you need to do is to setup an `MX record` for `subdomain.yourdomain.example` and point it to the **Google's mail servers**. The specific procedures are documented on [setting up MX records for G Suite Gmail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en&ref_topic=3035788)

Pretty much it should look something like:

| Host | Record type | Priority | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| subdomain.yourdomain.example | MX | 1 | ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. |

MX records in general are regardless of the domain name [zone level](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-6). In your case, the `subdomain` zone is the 3rd-level zone -- `example` being the root zone. It should work the same either setting up your email addresses as `@subdomain.yourdomain.example` or `@yourdomain.example`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding/creating alias to your domain in Gsuite settings, which will create additional addresses for all your mail addresses for example all email addresses ending with @yourdomain.com can also be reached at @subdomain.yourdomain.com please refer [this document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/175747?hl=en) for more elaborated information on this topic